# Firebase Auth call using Axios

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, axios

I am using react native as frontEnd and Firebase as backEnd for my application. I have created an API `192.168.0.104:8080/api/user/loginUsingEmail` which contains the following code :

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(data => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
            return res.json({message: `Successfully logged in`,token: token});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: errorCode, message : errorMessage
            });
        });
```

This is working perfectly fine using Postman.

Now the issue comes when I try to invoke the API using Axios to my react native project. The code is as follows :

`JSX` :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}>Sign In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

`Handler`:

```
const {email, password} = this.state;

        Axios.post('http://192.168.0.104:8080/api/user/loginUsingEmail', {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message })
        })
```

Here also all the errors and token comes perfectly fine. But in my LoadingScreen I have written as :

```
export default class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? "App" : "Auth");
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Loading ...</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large"></ActivityIndicator>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Now `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` does not get the proper `user` when we do an axios call. But if I change the handler to call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` directly, it works perfectly fine.

What I am doing wrong over here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Axios.post('http://192.168.0.104:8080/api/user/loginUsingEmail',`, the user is signed in to the service on `192.168.0.104:8080`. They are not signed in to the local Firebase instance that makes the call. Even if `192.168.0.104:8080` is you local machine, these two pieces of code run as two separate apps.

To sign in the user on the client, you will need to call one of the `firebase.auth().signIn...` methods in the client - and not just on the server. I'm not sure what the purpose of your `api/` handler is, but usually you should just have the call to sign in, inside your regular client-side code, as you did in:

> But if I change the handler to call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` directly, it works perfectly fine.

---

If you want to implement a custom sign in on your server, have a look at [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in the Firebase documentation, which describes the basic flow for that:

1. Your client collects the credentials needed to sign the user in.
2. Your client passes the credentials to the server over a secure connection.
3. The server validates the credentials.
4. The server mints a custom token based on the credentials.
5. The server passes the custom token to the client over a secure connection (for example, as the response to #2).
6. The client then signs in to Firebase by calling `signInWithCustomToken`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. My main question now is if we make this api as a global api (just as we do using `firebase deploy`), then my approach will work fine ?

Comment: If you want to run your custom server-side code on Firebase, have a look at Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: yes I know about the functions. Now if the do the deploy of functions and then do an axios post over the global api,  then `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` will work ?

Comment: There is no `signInWithEmailAndPassword` in the Node.js Admin SDK that you'll be using in Cloud Functions. That's why I described and linked the entire flow of implemeniting your own server-side auth above.